# c# console linux search groups of users

Tags: c#, ldap

I am making a program that needs to search all user groups in AD, but it is only bringing the last group of users searched.
Has anyone used Novell Directory Ldap to do this type of research?
Even putting the foreach it only shows the last group, the user, I need all groups.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Configuration;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;

namespace LdapApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host = "192.168.15.1";
            string user = "svcproxy";
            string password = "xxxx";
            int port = 389;
            int version = LdapConnection.Ldap_V3;
    
            int searchScope = LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB;
            string searchFilter = "sAMAccountName=ronaldo.terranova";
            string searchBase = "CN=Users,DC=ronaldoterranova,DC=local";

            LdapSearchConstraints constraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
            constraints.TimeLimit = 10000;

            var conn = new LdapConnection();
            conn.SecureSocketLayer = false;
            conn.Connect(host, port);
            conn.Bind(version, user, password);

            var users = new HashSet<string>();
            LdapSearchResults searchResult = conn.Search(
                searchBase,
                searchScope,
                searchFilter,
                null,
                false);
            while (searchResult.hasMore())
            {
                var nextEntry = searchResult.next();                
                nextEntry.getAttributeSet();
                var attr = nextEntry.getAttribute("memberOf");
                
                
                if(attr == null)
                {
                    users.Add(nextEntry.getAttribute("distinguishedName").StringValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    users.Add(nextEntry.getAttribute("memberOf").StringValue);                    
                }
            }

            foreach(var usr in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(usr);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer on the behalf of the author*:

Solved the problema, while alter to:

```
while (searchResult.hasMore())
            {
                LdapEntry nextEntry = null;
                nextEntry = searchResult.next();
                
                var attr = nextEntry.getAttribute("memberOf");

                IEnumerator ienum = nextEntry.getAttribute("memberOf").StringValues;
                while (ienum.MoveNext())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ienum.Current);
                }                
            }
```